# Inner Join Multiple Tables on a Nested Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I am using SQL-Server.

I want to run a nested query, get the results and do two inner joins on the complete nested query results.

My nested query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
table1.unique_id,
table1.a1,
table1.a2,
table1.cty, 
table1.ctry,
FROM table1
WHERE table1.unique_id IN (
    SELECT 
    unique_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE age = 22
)
```

The query returns the columns I want where all users are 22 years old.

I now want to combine 2 separate queries onto this one from two different tables, one being to get a phone number and one being to get an email. All tables share the field "unique_id" and I want to join the emails table and phone table to this query using unique_id.

```
SELECT 
table3.phone_number1
table3.phone_number2
FROM table3;

SELECT 
table4.email
FROM table4;
```

I basically want something like this but I can't get the syntax/formatting right:

```
SELECT 
table1.unique_id,
table1.a1,
table1.a2,
table1.cty, 
table1.ctry,
table3.phone_numer1,
table3.phone_numer2,
table4.email
FROM table1
WHERE table1.unique_id IN (
    SELECT 
    unique_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE age = 22
) 
INNER JOIN table3
ON table1.unique_id = table3.unique_id
INNER JOIN table4
ON table1.unique_id = table4.unique_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

After receiving help from the answers here, I realized that my table4 email table has more rows than I was expecting. The table is setup as follows:
[image]

I want to only get the email value from table4 with the highest email_id... in this case that would be d@gmail.com due to it having the highest email value.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in the query is incorrect in the following way: you have placed your `WHERE` clause between your `FROM` and the associated `JOIN`s.

The code that you have posted should mostly work, but you need to move the `WHERE` clause, and its subquery, to a position *after* the `JOIN`s.

Alternatively, you could restate the subquery as

```
INNER JOIN table2
   ON table1.unique_id = table2.unique_id
```

with the condition of `age = 22` in a `WHERE` clause that follows all of the `JOIN`s.

Either way, your `WHERE` must be placed after any `JOIN`s are defined.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following code:**

```
SELECT 
table1.unique_id,
table1.a1,
table1.a2,
table1.cty, 
table1.ctry,
table3.phone_numer1,
table3.phone_numer2,
table4.email
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table3
ON table1.unique_id = table3.unique_id
INNER JOIN table4
ON table1.unique_id = table4.unique_id
WHERE table1.unique_id IN (
    SELECT 
    unique_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE age = 22
)
```

Or another way:

```
select D.*,
table3.phone_numer1,
table3.phone_numer2,
table4.email

from
(
    SELECT 
    table1.unique_id,
    table1.a1,
    table1.a2,
    table1.cty, 
    table1.ctry,
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.unique_id IN (
        SELECT 
        unique_id
        FROM table2
        WHERE age = 22
    ) 
) as D
INNER JOIN table3
ON D.unique_id = table3.unique_id
INNER JOIN table4
ON D.unique_id = table4.unique_id
```

Considering that your table in which the email information is stored has the following structure, we act as follows.

```
unique_id , email_ID , email
```

Using Windows Functions and using the following code, the last email related to each unique_id is selected. Then it is enough to join this table to other tables.

```
select T1.Unid,  T1.email_ID , T1.email from 
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t.unique_id order by t.unique_id desc) as Unid,  t.email_ID , t.email  from table4 t
) T1 where T1.Unid = 1
```

And in the end, your query will look like this.

```
SELECT 
table1.unique_id,
table1.a1,
table1.a2,
table1.cty, 
table1.ctry,
table3.phone_numer1,
table3.phone_numer2,
table4.email
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table3
ON table1.unique_id = table3.unique_id
INNER JOIN 
(
select T1.Unid,  T1.email_ID , T1.email from 
    (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t.unique_id order by t.email_ID desc) as Unid,  t.email_ID , t.email  from table4 t
    ) T1 where T1.Unid = 1
) table4
ON table1.unique_id = table4.unique_id
WHERE table1.unique_id IN 
(
    SELECT 
    unique_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE age = 22
)
```

If this answer was helpful, please select it as the answer. By checking the mark.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me achieve exactly what I was looking for. If my email table would have multiple emails and they're sorted in order by email_id, email... how would I only join the newest email? As in only join the email with the highest email_Id. When I do it currently, I join with all emails in the table.

Comment: Please enter the table structure that contains the email field here to modify the query to your request. Also keep in mind that there must be a field that identifies the last email entered. For example, the date of inserting the email in the table or. . .
Also, if this answer was useful, specify it as an answer and check it. @jadenohiokan

Comment: I have done this. Thanks again @Gezgalee

Comment: I corrected and updated the answer based on your new question. @jadenohiokan